# Guardar imagen en una carpeta local con PHP

Tags: php, php7, php5

Quiero guardar la imagen que me ingresar desde html en una carpeta, ya que me la esta guardando el la carpeta general del proyecto, como podría hacer para que se guarde en una carpeta local que este dentro de la carpera general que se pueda llamar imágenes o fotos.

Gracias

```
<?php

$imagenCodificada = file_get_contents("php://input");
if(strlen($imagenCodificada) <= 0) exit("No se recibió ninguna imagen");

$imagenCodificadaLimpia = str_replace("data:image/png;base64,", "", urldecode($imagenCodificada));


$imagenDecodificada = base64_decode($imagenCodificadaLimpia);


$nombreImagenGuardada = "foto_" . uniqid() . ".png";


file_put_contents($nombreImagenGuardada, $imagenDecodificada);


exit($nombreImagenGuardada);
?>
```

Comment: No estas asignando ninguna ruta, así que se guarda en la carpeta actual de trabajo. Echa un vistazo a la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-put-contents.php) para tener claro como trabaja la función que estas usando para almacenar en disco.

Answer (score 1):

El segundo parametro de la función file_put_contents es el nombre con el que vas a guardar el archivo subido. Esto incluye la ruta / carpeta de donde se va a guardar.

Al solamente especificar el nombre del archivo, te lo guarda en la carpeta donde se ejecuta el script.

Si por ejemplo quieres guardarlo en la carpeta "images", crea la carpeta images e indica en la función dicha carpeta de la siguiente manera

```
file_put_contents( 'images/'.$imagenDecodificada,$nombreImagenGuardada);
```

Comment: No, el primer parámetro de [file_put_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-put-contents.php) es ruta + nombre de archivo y el segundo parámetro es el contenido.

Comment: Cierto, no se porque a la hora de escribir la respuesta estaba pensando en move_uploaded_file(). 
Edito la respuesta.
Gracias